# Include custom JS without child theme

Tags: customization, javascript, child-theme

Is there a way to include custom JavaScript on a website, without using a child theme?

I am currently working on a customers website. Unfortunately he somehow managed to make it kind of impossible to create a child theme of his main theme. I just need to add a few lines of code. So is there a way to do this without adding a child theme?